# What is an effective way to test a new public node on your own LAN?

Tags: full-node, network, connection

I followed [CoinCashew's instructions](https://github.com/coincashew/coincashew/blob/master/coins/overview-xmr/guide-or-how-to-run-a-full-node.md) to build a public node.  I'd like to use it.  The command `ss | grep 18081 | less` shows that there are no connections on that port, and `ss | grep 18080 | less` shows that there are plenty on the 18080 (which I believe is required to sync the blockchain).  The node is running on one of the computers connected to my ISP router, so the shortest connection would be from my phone's 192.168 address to the 192.168 address of the node, but I exposed it on the public address assigned me by my ISP.  Does that matter?

Is there a site where I can enter my public IP address (the IP that everything connected to my router gets when visiting whatismyipaddress.com) and have it try to verify that my public node works?  I would like to use it for the Monero wallet on my phone even when I'm at home but I don't know if my ISP will tolerate a request to send information from my public IP back to my public IP (or if the router is smart enough to redirect the request from one local connection to another).  It seems like when I enter the public IP on my phone, it should reach my node and work, but it always says "Connection Error".

I believe the relevant entries in my config file are:

```
rpc-restricted-bind-ip=0.0.0.0
rpc-restricted-bind-port=18089
public-node=true # Advertises the RPC-restricted port over p2p peer lists
```

Answer (score 1):

CoinCashew's instructions include a graphic which is misleading.  It suggests configuring ports 18080 and 18081, but the rest of the post uses port 18089 instead of port 18081.  After reconfiguring my router and my local firewall to use 18089 instead of 18081, the built-in TEST function for connecting to remote nodes on the Monero wallet on my phone (Monerujo) was able to connect to my node.

The fact that my phone and the remote node I chose to use connect to the Internet using the same IP address does not matter.  It may, however interfere with the operations the wallet does: The connection test passes, but after connecting, it disconnects without updating my wallet and asks for a different remote node.

I don't have an answer for the second question, "Is there a site where I can enter my public IP address (the IP that everything connected to my router gets when visiting whatismyipaddress.com) and have it try to verify that my public node works?"